# Neo4j - Cypher query not showing relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing a query to bring all relationships of the recipes having `fibre > 30` and `calories` in the range of [1000,2000]. (A little background: recipes are connected with `recipe_types` and many more nodes).

I tried the CQL below:

```
MATCH (r:recipe)-[]->()
WHERE 
toInt(r.fibre) >= 30 AND 
toInt(r.calories) >= 1000 AND toInt(r.calories) <= 20000
RETURN r
LIMIT 100
```

But, it shows the nodes of recipes only, without any relationship.

Comment: Highly recommended that you keep your int values as ints when save them in the graph. That way you won't need to use toInt() on them, and if you decide to index them (or place a unique constraint on them), it will be able to take advantage of that (you lose that when you do toInt(). Lastly, you can improve your calorie bounds checking by doing "AND 1000 <= r.calories <= 20000"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *show* relationships you should *return* them:

```
MATCH (r:recipe)-[rel]->(other_node)
WHERE 
toInt(r.fibre) >= 30 AND 
toInt(r.calories) >= 1000 AND toInt(r.calories) <= 20000
RETURN r, rel, other_node
LIMIT 100
```